Error ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector) en Angular
Estoy intentando consumir una api en angular pero me sale este error, he creado un servicio donde hago una petición HTTP para consumir imágenes y videos de una api(pexels), pero me sale un error y no se a que se debe, os dejo el código por si he cometido algún fallo.
Este es el código del servicio:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GaleriaService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/'; // URL de la API

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // Obtener imágenes y videos
  getMedios(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}

Y aquí está el código del componente donde quiero inyectar el servicio:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GaleriaService } from '../../services/galeria.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-galeria',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './galeria.component.html',
  styleUrl: './galeria.component.css',
})
export class GaleriaComponent implements OnInit {
  medios: any[] = [];
  constructor(private galeriaService: GaleriaService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cargarMedios();
  }

  cargarMedios(): void {
    this.galeriaService.getMedios().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.medios = data;
    });
  }
}

El error que me sale en la consola:

Ps: Estoy trabajando con la última versión de angular

No te falta el HttpClientModule??? https://angular.dev/guide/http/setup  // además, los errores van como texto por favor.

Asumiendo que estás con alguna versión reciente de Angular y considerando que no has publicado el app.config.ts, lo más probable es que en tu app.config.ts, estés sin incluir el HttpClient.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: ConfigFactory,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
    },
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideHttpClient(), // Este es el que te falta.
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
};


Resuelto el problema gracias me faltaba justo eso!

Un gusto colaborar. Para siguientes preguntas, incluye más detalles para evitar ir a ciegas, con detalles vamos con nitro a la respuesta :D Saludos y ¡felices fiestas!
